# On click run PHP code and paste result in text box?

Tags: php, jquery, textbox, onclick, copy-paste

I have some php code that generates a random password. Next to a text box I have some text which says "click to Generate a random password".

What I am looking to achieve is when the text in double quotes above is clicked that the PHP code is run and the generated random password is then pasted into the text box which is beside the text above in double quotes.

How could do this? I am thinking maybe jQuery but not sure how I would do what I want above.

Comment: if you could put your html here, would be simple to add the script.

Comment: Hi,

Its just a simple form with a text box.

Comment: yes, and it would be stupid to involve PHP in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are... complete and working example :)
Put files 'index.html' and 'passgenerator.php' into same directory.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#generate').click(function(){
                    $.get('passgenerator.php', function(data) {
                        $('[name=password]').val(data);
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="password">
            <input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate password">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

passgenerator.php

```
<?php
echo sha1(uniqid());
?>
```

Comment: Wow! That's some password the poor user's going to need to remember. sha1() produces as 40-character string.

Comment: It's ok i understand the PHP part of things so can alter that with my own code.

Comment: @David Powers: it is just example, to show it realy works... Maaaaan...<br/>@PHPLOVER: sure, feel free to suit it your needs :)

Answer (score 2):

either use ajax to call the script page that generates the password or like col. shrapnel says port the generating function to javascript (which is a better idea)

Example (with jquery using ajax)

```
$.get("/PasswordGenerator.php",function(password)
{
    $("#TextboxID").val( password );
});
```

where TextboxID is the id of the textbox u want the password to be added to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in php. Just do it in javascript. Here is a very neat tutorial that should show you the step by step instructions:
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/random.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this ajax call to get the content using ajax and display it on the div.

```
$("#generate").click(function(){
 $.get('url:to:urPHP',{

                    data:urData
                  },function(data){
                  $("#generatedPassword").html(data);
                  });

});
<input type="" id="generate" value="click to Generate a random password" />
<div id="generatedPassword">

<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Patrick Evans** is right. You can setup your form like this :

```
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="generate();">
```

And in  section you have to define a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generate(){
$.get("/PasswordGenerator.php",function(password)
{
    $("#TextboxID").val( password );
});
}
</script>
```